# ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, cursor, fetch, rowcount

I created a procedure in oracle database that returns data in a ref-cursor, and I want it to return the rowcount of this cursor also as an output variable. After testing, the P_count variable is filled correctly, but when I tried to open the cursor an 'ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence' error fired. I have read before about it and I found that the problem is because I am using a fetch statement in my code. But till now I did not discover how to resolve it. Any helps are appreciated, thank you. Below is my Procedure:

```
PROCEDURE IS_CLIENT_LOGGED_IN (
  P_CLIENT_NUM  Varchar2,
  P_CURSOR out  SYS_REFCURSOR ,
  P_COUNT OUT   NUMBER,
  P_ERROR out   Varchar2
) AS
  cur_rec Varchar2(1024);
BEGIN
   BEGIN 
     Open P_CURSOR FOR
       SELECT ID
         FROM tbl_registration
        WHERE tbl_client_id = P_CLIENT_NUM  
          AND tbl_logout_date is null;

     LOOP
      FETCH P_CURSOR INTO cur_rec;  
      EXIT WHEN P_CURSOR%notfound;
      P_COUNT := P_CURSOR%rowcount;--will return row number beginning with 1
     END LOOP;
   EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
     P_ERROR := 'Unable to select Data from tbl_registration' ||SQLERRM;
   END;    
END IS_CLIENT_LOGGED_IN;
```

Comment: You should close the cursor after you have used it.

Comment: What is the purpose of your procedure? Usually when you return a `SYS_REFCURSOR` then records are fetched by the invoking block. You should not return cursor where rows are already fetched.

Comment: This procedure is implemented in another one: So I need a rowcount to return a counter for looping in the other procedure, and a cursor to work with the retrieved data also in the other procedure. When I added CLOSE P_CURSOR before LOOP, the cursor could not be defined while looping, but when I added after END LOOP it returned ORA-24338 statement handle not executed. Thank you @WernfriedDomscheit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment the procedure should be like this:

```
PROCEDURE IS_CLIENT_LOGGED_IN (
  P_CLIENT_NUM  Varchar2,
  P_CURSOR out  SYS_REFCURSOR ,
  P_COUNT OUT   NUMBER,
  P_ERROR out   Varchar2
) AS
  cur_rec Varchar2(1024);
BEGIN
     Open P_CURSOR FOR
       SELECT ID
         FROM tbl_registration
        WHERE tbl_client_id = P_CLIENT_NUM  
          AND tbl_logout_date is null;

     LOOP
      FETCH P_CURSOR INTO cur_rec;  
      EXIT WHEN P_CURSOR%notfound;
      P_COUNT := P_CURSOR%rowcount;--will return row number beginning with 1
     END LOOP;
     CLOSE P_CURSOR;

     Open P_CURSOR FOR
       SELECT ID
         FROM tbl_registration
        WHERE tbl_client_id = P_CLIENT_NUM  
          AND tbl_logout_date is null;

   EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
     P_ERROR := 'Unable to select Data from tbl_registration' ||SQLERRM;
END IS_CLIENT_LOGGED_IN;
```

Not very efficient, but that's what you asked for.
Anyway, I don't see any reason to increment `P_COUNT` one-by-one.

Make

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO P_COUNT
     FROM tbl_registration
    WHERE tbl_client_id = P_CLIENT_NUM  
      AND tbl_logout_date is null;

Open P_CURSOR FOR
   SELECT ID
     FROM tbl_registration
    WHERE tbl_client_id = P_CLIENT_NUM  
      AND tbl_logout_date is null;
```

to get the same.

Comment: Actually I was trying to avoid two selections and get the result from one selection by counting the cursor rows, thanks anyway @Wernfried Domscheit